# Pairing images as np arrays into a specific format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have 2 images, X and Y, as numpy arrays, each of shape (3, 30, 30): that is, 3 channels (RGB), each of height and width 30 pixels. I'd like to pair them up into a numpy array to get a specific output shape:

```
my_pair = pair_up_images(X, Y)
my_pair.shape = (2, 3, 30, 30)
```

Such that I can get the original images by slicing:

```
my_pair[0] == X
my_pair[1] == Y
```

After a few attempts, I keep getting either:

> - my_pair.shape = (2,) #By converting the images into lists and adding them.

This works as well, but the next step in the pipeline just requires a shape (2, 3, 30, 30)

> - my_pair.shape = (6, 30, 30) # using np.vstack
> - my_pair.shape = (3, 60, 30) # using np.hstack

Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with `np.array([im1, im2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
Z = np.array([X, Y])

Z.shape
Out[62]: (2, 3, 30, 30)
```